# Django database access optimization: Efficient creation of many-to-many relationships (between existing objects)

Tags: django, postgresql, optimization, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I'm using Django 2.2 with a PostgreSQL database.

I have two models: `Gene` and `Annotation` and need to create and link (many-to-many) **thousands** of Genes and Annotations at the same time.

```py
class Gene(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    annotation = models.ManyToManyField(Annotation)
```

```py
class Annotation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

I already found a way to create the objects very efficiently:

```py
Gene.objects.bulk_create([Gene(identifier=identifier) for identifier in gene_id_set])
```

This is my Django-docs-inspired way to create relationships:

```py
relationships = {
    'gene1': ['anno1', 'anno2'],
    'gene2': ['anno3'],
    ...
}

for gene in relationships:
    gene = Annotation.objects.get(pk='gene1')
    gene.annotation_set.set([Annotation.objects.get(pk=anno) for anno in relationships[gene])
```

But this is very clumsy: It hits the database 4 times! Is there not a better way, using Django-built-in-tools or [raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/)?

The many-to-many table (`myapp_gene_annotation`) looks like this:

```
id gene_id   annotation_id
1  gene1       anno1
2  gene1       anno2
3  gene2       anno3
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we can create `Gene_annotation` objects: the implicit model Django has constructed for the `ManyToMany` table, like:

```
through_model = Gene.annotation.through

objs = [
    through_model(gene_id=gene_id, annotation_id=anno_id)
    for gene_id, rels in relationships.items()
    for anno_id in rels
]
```

Now we can perform a bulk insert in the table of the `through_model`:

```
through_model.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

You should of course only add the relations *after* you have added the `Gene`s and `Annotation`s, since otherwise, the foreign key constraints at the database side will raise an error.

We will here insert all the relations in *one* time. If the table is huge, this might result in multiple queries, but still it is more efficient than querying once per relation.